# end for=0 at the end of a for loop

Tags: pdftex, algorithms, algorithmic

I'm not sure why I get two extra characters at the end of the for loop. Looking at other answers on StackExchange indicates I'm not suppose to use both algorithm and algorithmic and that its better to stick to one.

However, removing either does not produce the results I want.

Here is the code.

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Forward calculation for pair HMMs}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\REQUIRE Set $f^{\mathrm{M}}(0,0)=1 f^{\mathrm{X}}(0,0)=f^{\mathrm{Y}}(0,0)= f^{*}(i,-1) = f^{*}(-1, j) = 0$
\FOR{$i=0, \ldots, n, j=0, \ldots, m \text { except }(0,0)$}

\begin{aligned}
f^{\mathrm{M}}(i, j) & = p_{I_{i} O_{j}}\left[a_{MM} (f^{\mathrm{M}}(i-1, j-1))+\\
& \quad \quad \left.a_{XM}\left(f^{\mathrm{X}}(i-1, j-1)\right)+a_{YM}(f^{\mathrm{Y}}(i-1, j-1)\right)\right] \\
f^{\mathrm{X}}(i, j) & = q_{I_{i}}\left[a_{MX} f^{\mathrm{M}}(i-1, j)+a_{XX} f^{\mathrm{X}}(i-1, j)\right] \\
f^{\mathrm{Y}}(i, j) & = q_{O_{j}}\left[a_{MY} f^{\mathrm{M}}(i, j-1)+a_{YY} f^{\mathrm{Y}}(i, j-1)\right]\\
\end{aligned}

\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't load both `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode`. You're using the syntax pertaining to the former.

Here's a fixed version; please note the changes, in particular enclosing `aligned` in `$...$` and adding `\STATE`.

I also removed all `\left` and `\right`, which did nothing except producing errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Forward calculation for pair HMMs}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\REQUIRE Set $f^{\mathrm{M}}(0,0)=1$, $f^{\mathrm{X}}(0,0)=
  f^{\mathrm{Y}}(0,0)= f^{*}(i,-1) = f^{*}(-1, j) = 0$
\FOR{$i=0, \dots, n$, $j=0, \dots, m$ except $(0,0)$}
\STATE $\begin{aligned}
f^{\mathrm{M}}(i, j) & = p_{I_{i} O_{j}}[a_{MM} (f^{\mathrm{M}}(i-1, j-1))+\\
& \quad \quad a_{XM}f^{\mathrm{X}}(i-1, j-1))+a_{YM}(f^{\mathrm{Y}}(i-1, j-1))] \\
f^{\mathrm{X}}(i, j) & = q_{I_{i}}[a_{MX} f^{\mathrm{M}}(i-1, j)+a_{XX} f^{\mathrm{X}}(i-1, j)] \\
f^{\mathrm{Y}}(i, j) & = q_{O_{j}}[a_{MY} f^{\mathrm{M}}(i, j-1)+a_{YY} f^{\mathrm{Y}}(i, j-1)]\\
\end{aligned}$
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's strange. I still get the =0 at the end of for loop.

Comment: The =0 doesn't appear when I compile it on its own. However, it gives the same error when I include them in my document.

Comment: @TriposG The appearance of `=0` is a clear sign that your document loads `algpseudocode`.